# How to serve another websites content on the fly on my own domain?

Tags: php

I am posting here hoping to get some ideas on how my employers website is being copied.

So basically my employers website is located [here](http://bit.ly/neonandm) and today we discovered that another unrelated website located [here](http://www.ace-neonsigns.com/) has copied every single publicly accessible page on the website.

Now here's the catch, it does not seem that they just spidered the site and are now serving HTML copies from their server.  Instead, every time a page is requested on that site, it makes a live query to our website to serve that content.  It also replaces on the fly things like email and domains with their domain in emails.

So my question is, how might the person doing this to us be doing it, from a code perspective?

I would like to find out how this is possible so that I can also understand it and more importantly hopefully put a stop and prevent it from happening anymore?

Apologize in advance if this is not a Stack Overflow type question, I believe it is though.  If not I can move it to a different Stack Exchange site if another fits better.

Comment: Proxy. There are plenty of answers with details if you search for "how to proxy web services calls in XXXX [you favorite language]" if you need legitimate reason to get the source.

Comment: It is very simple to do. They just makes a request to your server. Gets the content. Do the replace and then return it to the user.

I would start with contacting them and tell them to stop.

And if they don't stop figure out which IP they do the requests from and then you can block them or serve something else to them

Comment: Likely this question is offtopic on all SE sites as it essentially looking for legal advice... webmasters (as suggested by @JakeGould) or http://serverfault.com are possible sites where such question may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my question is, how might the person doing this to us be doing it,
>   from a code perspective?

Easy. They are somehow crawling the structure of your site, ripping it apart to change content & then reconstructing it on their domain.  For a fun example of how this can be done, check out [Meowbify](http://meowbify.com).

That said, you might be able to block them via IP address if you check your server’s access logs.  Just tail the logs like so. I am assuming you are on a Linux setup running Apache:

```
tail -f -n 200 /var/log/apache/access.log
```

Now with that in place, go to a page on this rogue site, click it & see what IP address pops up. For this example’s sake, let’s say it’s `123.456.789.0`. Got that? Well, using Apache you can do the following in an `.htaccess` file:

```
order allow,deny
deny from 123.456.789.0
allow from all
```

This would effectively block all web server access from the IP address `123.456.789.0`.

Or you could use [`iptables`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-block-an-ip-on-my-linux-server/) to completely block network access like so:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 123.456.789.0 -j DROP
```

You might need to run that as `sudo` like so:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 123.456.789.0 -j DROP
```

That said, this might be like playing [Whack-A-Mole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whac-A-Mole). So you might want to come up with a different strategy. For example, is your site coded in PHP? Is it an off the shelf system or was it custom built? Instead of doing it on a system level with `iptables` or on a web service level like Apache, you might want to just come up with a PHP-based method of controlling access.

Or you could even be sneakier. Such as coding your site to send gibberish content to the other site when the access via an IP address. Like just piles of `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.` junk that gets sent to the unwanted site when you detect they are there.

But what this all boils down to is the Internet ultimately allows for content to be scraped like this. Any site can be scraped & have content reappropriated. It doesn’t happen that much because socially it's just wrong & it’s not sustainable since your creation of your own work implies copyright.

So knowing the copyright angle, the nuclear option would be to contact the website’s host and make a copyright claim. They would cut off their service for ripping off your work.  But it’s never 100% easy to do that. And you never know if the ISP will be cooperative or not.